# C# how do i make picturebox to form

Tags: c#, picturebox, windows-mobile-6

I'm unable to make my pictureboxes to be shown on form. Am i doing it wrong or? This is my code:

```
static Bitmap[] pictures = new Bitmap[9];
PictureBox[] picBox= new PictureBox[9];
```

on the constructor :

```
            pictures[1] = new Bitmap(@"1.1Bright.jpg");

         *  picBox[1].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(25, 7);
            picBox[1].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            picBox[1].ClientSize = new Size(53, 40);
            picBox[1].Image = pictures[1];
```

I keep getting nullreferenceexception error on *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it:

```
picBox[0] = new PictureBox();   
this.Controls.Add(this.picBox[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You haven't set `picBox[1]` to reference anything. You need something like:

```
picBox[1] = new PictureBox();
```

Do you *really* want the `pictures` variable to be static though? The array contents will be overwritten every time you create an instance of the form...